# WooCommerce stock not updating

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, woocommerce, stock

I'm using the Woo Product Importer plugin to update my WooCommerce products and all seems to be working except for a problem with the stock count.

After updating the products using the plugin, the stock count on the front end and on the back end product list does not reflect the changes to the CSV, however if i click an individual product and view the stock count it does reflect the changes, if i then click update the front end will be updated as well.

I've checked the postmeta table in the database and the stock count in there also reflects the changes in the CSV, it seems the only way to get the stock count to display is to click update on every individual product which just isn't feasible with thousands of products and daily updates.

Does anyone know how i could solve this issue, perhaps some sort of mass update for each product to make it re-check the stock count?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a caching issue, take a look at the wp_options table and try to find something related to it.

Another approach is to modify the imported plugin to include the hook that updates the product from the frontend.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
"stock_quantity": "24.54"
"manage_stock": 500
}
```

Just add `manage_stock = true`.